# Gmail will remove "Less secure apps" on the 30th of May. What does that mean for javax mail?

Tags: java, gmail

Google is removing the access to gmail for "Less secure apps"  starting the 1st of April ([Gmail notification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=7&p=less-secure-apps&hl=en-GB&authuser=7&visit_id=637836160667495013-1674968398&rd=1)).

That probably means that we won't be able to use javax mail with a gmail account anymore. Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: not exactly, you probably will need to switch to app password. Check point 3 here 
https://mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/
and also this for google app passwords https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?p=InvalidSecondFactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using imaplib then The easiest fix for the depiction of less secure apps is to switch to using an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en#:%7E:text=An%20App%20Password%20is%20a,2%2DStep%20Verification%20turned%20on.).

Another option would be to swtich to using [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)  javax mail appears to support that [Oauth2](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); // required for Gmail
props.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, oauth2_access_token);
```

[How to create a Apps Password for connecting to Google's SMTP server.](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IGOt3zo98Xw)